# dojo ajax call using xhr post and json

Tags: spring-mvc, dojo

I am not able to post a dojo form via xhr call of dojo 1.8 but its happening through deprecated method dojo.xhrPost. Please see the code fragment that I used.

This is portion from jsp for dojo ajax call

```
require(["dojo/request/xhr"],function(xhr){
    xhr('http://localhost:8080/myApp/call',{
        data:  'callerName',
        method:"POST",
        load: function(data, ioargs) {
             alert("The message is: " +  ioargs.xhr.status);  
             },
             error: function(error){
             alert("Returned: " + error);
             }
    });
    });
<form data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Form" name="callerName" id="callerName">
    ...here are dojo input types
</form>
```

Below is spring controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/call",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView saveData3(HttpServletRequest req, @ModelAttribute Caller    caller){}
```

Here I am not getting the values from form to caller model attribute. but the call is happening.
Instead of this ajax call if I go for deprecated call a below, the values are getting bound.

```
dojo.xhrPost({
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/myApp/call',
    form: 'callerName',
    load: function(response) {
    }
```

for latest call in 1.8 instead of argument 'data', I tried with 'form' still not happening. What can be this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Dojo has [deprecated the `load` and `error` callback attributes in favor of deferreds/promises](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/releasenotes/migration-2.0.html).

- Sample of [new code with deferreds code below old code with callbacks](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/releasenotes/migration-2.0.html#xhr-and-io-requests).
- Another [sample](http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/post-request-using-new-dojo-request-xhr-td3987429.html).

---

I thought Dojo would maintain backwards compatibility until 2.0, but perhaps it was dropped (ah.. perhaps 1.8 supports the old syntax if you require the old `dojo/_base/xhr`).

Also, note it is better to require `dojo/request` instead of `dojo/request/xhr` directly.

**update:** *Why `dojo/request` is preferred over `dojo/request/xhr`:*

`dojo/request` is a higher level abstraction than `dojo/request/xhr`. So it is:

- more portable: `dojo/request` automatically selects the proper provider and works in both the client and server. `dojo/request/xhr` will not work on the server (node.js) and `dojo/request/node` will not work on the client (browser).
- more flexible. In the future, perhaps a better provider will be added. `dojo/request` can use the best provider without any changes to your code. Also, providers can be configured based on the URL. An example use case would be using `dojo/request/xhr` for same domain requests and `dojo/request/script` for cross domain requests.

sources:

- [kitsonk, core Dojo contributor](http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/post-request-using-new-dojo-request-xhr-tp3987429p3987434.html)
- [`dojo/request/registry` documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/request/registry.html#dojo-request-registry)
- [`dojo/request` documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/request.html)

Comment: can you give example for your answer please!

Comment: @SathishKumarkk: There are links to two examples in the answer.

Comment: ya but when I try this, my spring controller is not called Y?

Comment: @Leftium Why is requiring `dojo/request` better than `dojo/request/xhr`? Is requiring `dojo/request`  like `dojo/request/*` a la Java?

Comment: @EricAlberson: `dojo/request` is a higher level abstraction. More portable and flexible. I updated my answer with more details.